# How to find and replace a file path (along with special characters) using SED command

Tags: linux, sed

How to find and replace a file path like `a/b/c/d` into `x/y/z` using **sed** command?

I tried `sed -i -e 's/a/\b/\c/\d/x/\y/\z' file.txt` but it did not work.

Comment: The close reason is somewhat unclear. You are expected to demonstrate some effort, typically what you tried and how it failed, or at the very least what you searched for and what you found, and how you found it hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Just use another separator for `s` command. You can use any character. Just `/` is the most popular one. I like `@` or `#`. Then you have to escape that character.

```
sed 's@a/b/c/d@x/y/z@'
```

> but it did not work

To escape `/` use `\/` not `/\`. The `\` needs to be in front of `/`. You could:

```
sed 's/a\/b\/c\/d/x\/y\/z/'
```